# Copy from a measurement to another measurement in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

Having the following statement:

```
SELECT * INTO ZZZD FROM P4978
```

Output:

```
result
time                    written
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z    231
```

Using:

```
SELECT * FROM ZZZD
```

I get only 7 lines even if there where 231 lines written. I can't figure why there are only 7 lines. Is there some setting or this is a defect? I'm not able to copy from a measurement to another measurement more than 7 lines.

Comment: Fixed the problem using the GROUP BY, now I have the following query:    SELECT * INTO ZZZD FROM P4978 GROUP BY "component"

Answer (score 18):

If you want an exact copy use:

```
SELECT * INTO ZZZD FROM P4978 group by *
```

If you don't specify `group by *`, the tags will turn into fields.

You can verify the tags with `show tag keys from ZZZD` and the fields with `show field keys from ZZZD`

Source: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/continuous_queries/#common-issues-with-basic-syntax  scroll to **issue-4**

Answer (score 2):

Into clause is now working with influxDB 0.12 and above.

```
SELECT * INTO ZZZD FROM P4978
```

This will work

Answer (score -3):

The INTO clause is intended for use with the downsampling continuous queries. Kapacitor is a better tool for copying data from one measurement to another.

Comment: please could you explain how to do this?